# Launch Composable bottomsheet from native UI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm unable to find ways to launch a bottomsheet from a function without marking it as @Composable.

When we used google material bottom sheet dialog fragment, we didn't need any container, just the support fragment manager and it used to show above the activity or fragment.

But in a project that already contains native UI, if I had to start a composable bottomsheet then, I have to create a container and then apply `setContent` on top of it to attach my composable bottomsheet.

Let me know if someone has any workaround on how to open a composable bottomsheet without a container and without annotating the launcher method as @Composable.